# Fixed width for <code> element using twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a set of rows in a table, containing code-blocks, looking like this:

```
<td style='border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;'>
    <div>
        <code>-1245</code>
    </div>                                 
    <br />                                 
    <div>
        <code>-12455</code>
    </div>                                  
    <br />                                 
    <div>
        <code>-1245</code>
    </div>                                
    <br />                                 
    <div>
        <code>-1245</code>
    </div>                                  
    <br />                                 
    <div>
        <code>-1245</code>
    </div>  
</td>
```

And some CSS, like so:

```
<style scoped>
    .k-grid code {
        width: 45px;
        color: lightslategray;
    }
</style>
```

My problem here is that I need the code boxes to have all the same width, and not a width based on the content (fluid like).

I.e. when I have the number 1234, the box is displayed with one width, and when I have the number 12345, the box is expanded to another width.

I cannot seem to override this locally using the CSS. Any suggestions?

**Update**

Found a solution that suits my needs, based on the answers below.
Css:

```css
.k-grid code {
    line-height: 1.25;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    color: lightslategray;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML [`<code>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code) element is an *inline* wrapper. In order to apply *width*, you need to change type of display to `block` or `inline-block`:

```css
td code {
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  margin: 2px 0;
}
```

In this case, you won't need to wrap `<code>` elements by `<div>`:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <code>-1245</code>
        <code>-12455</code>
        <code>-1245</code>
        <code>-1245</code>
        <code>-1245</code>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the **[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/imusIVu/1/edit)**.

### Update

First I should note that I used `margin` property before only for the previous demo, remove that. Also, It's better to reset `line-height` property of `<code>` elements:

```css
td code {
  display: block; /* Or inline-block */
  width: 50px;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

TW Bootstrap applies a `margin-bottom` property to its `.progress` element. Reset the *margin* in your stylesheet if needed:

```css
.progress {
  margin: 0; /* <-- Override Bootstrap default style */
}
```

However, in this case I think it's better to place each line in a separate row (`<tr>`).
I created a Demo on the basis of your posted image.

Here is the **[JSBin Demo #2](http://jsbin.com/imusIVu/2/)**.

Comment: Thanks! However, this makes them go out of proportions in height. Since I can't add an image to a comment, please see my next post below for what I mean :)

Comment: @NicklasWinger You could always edit your own post to add additional information :) I've updated my answer, give it a try please.

Comment: Thank you again for great tips and help, but the <code> blocks and the progress bars are placed in three separate columnns in my template. My progress-bars also have som custom styling to them, as some of them are reversed (moving from right to left), they have centered text and they're adjusted to align the content on the rest of the template row. Your previous solution did the trick for me, and I will update my question in a short while :)

Answer (score 0):

Before:
[image: Before adding the css]

After:
[image: After adding the css]

I'd like to keep the height of the original "before" version, as this fits with the rest. Editing height doesn't seem to do the trick properly :S

Comment: Take a look at `padding` and `line-height` then.

Comment: You should also consider creating new `<tr>`s for each row too. Why are all of those rows contained within a single `<td>`?

Comment: I might be wrong here, but this is part of a kendo ui client row template, inside a grid component. The image you see above is an entire row in a dynamically produced table. Thus, adding tr's inside the td's makes the template go wonky :)

Comment: Makes sense. Sounds like a tough constraint to work within. Good luck!

Comment: Nightmare, to be honest :D Thanks :)